# Refactoring a WCF Trusted Facade

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, delegates, func

I'm attempting to refactor a "[trusted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/trusted-facade-service) [facade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/best-practices-intermediaries)" which currently wraps over 50 service calls to the backend. All calls have different signatures, but everything else is being repeated. The issue with the existing calls was that there was no attempt made to manage the connections, resulting in ephemeral ports remaining in the "BOUND" state.

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
public class ReportWeb : IReportWeb
{
    ReportService.ReportClient client = new ReportClient();
    ...
    
    public string[] GetAccounts() => client.GetAccounts();
}
```

**NEW CODE:**

```
private ChannelFactory<IReportService> _factory = null;
private IReportService _proxy = null;

private void OpenProxy()
{
    _factory = new ChannelFactory<IReportService>("NetTcpBinding_IReportService");
    _proxy = _factory.CreateChannel();
}

private void CloseProxy()
{
    ((IClientChannel)_proxy).Close();
    _factory.Close();
}
```

One of 50+ similar methods:

```
public string[] GetAccounts() // Different - name, params, and return type
{
    string[] accounts = null; // Different

    try
    {
        OpenProxy();
        accounts = _proxy.GetAccounts();  // Different
        CloseProxy();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        bool faulted = _factory.State == CommunicationState.Faulted;
        _factory.Abort();

        if (faulted)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(exception.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return accounts;
}
```

Another similar method:

```
//Another method
public ContractsInfo[] GetContracts(int contractId) // Different - 
    // name, params, and return type
{
    ContractsInfo[] contracts = null; // Different

    try
    {
        OpenProxy();
        contracts = _proxy.GetContracts(contractId); // Different
        CloseProxy();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        bool faulted = _factory.State == CommunicationState.Faulted;
        _factory.Abort();
        if (faulted)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(exception.Message);
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return contracts;
}
```

Calling code from Web Forms project:

```
public string[] GetAccounts()
{
    ReportClient client = NewReportClient();
    string[] results = null;

    try
    {
        results = client.GetAccounts();
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        client.Abort();
        throw ex;
    }
    return results;
}
```

There are over fifty other methods like GetData() with different signatures. They will all be identical except for the service call in each, which will vary in params and return type. I need a more abstract, or generic, way of coding this and thus adhere to the DRY principle. Would `Func<T, TResult> Delegate` be appropriate here? Either way, can someone suggest a best approach here with some stub code to illustrate?

Comment: The DRY principle you said means don't repeat yourself, that is, don't repeat the same thing. You have a lot of methods that are only slightly different so you want to design a generic way to reduce the amount of redundancy in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that this is the case where Generic method with can be applied. It is
possible to [read about Generics here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms379564(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Let me show a code example:

```
public class Foo
{ 
    public T GetDate<T, UArg>(UArg arg) where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, except this is a type of facade and all its methods have different names, params and return types. If I tried to go this route I would be changing the API and would then have to change 50+ API calls in the client as well? I've updated code to show what will be different. Thought using a Func<...> might work...

Comment: @IrishChieftain could you show, please, more examples of various methods like `GetData()`?

Comment: Done. Some methods have three or four different params and completely different return types. I tried extracting the exception to a method but ran into the "throw vs throw exception" conundrum.

Comment: @IrishChieftain Am I correctly understood that all these 50 methods are located in `ReportWeb` class? If yes, can you post code which calls these methods?

Comment: Added the client calling code.

Comment: @IrishChieftain thank you for your updates. I suppose like you said it is possible to use `Func`. I thought that `Template` pattern can be used here, but this is not that case as all 50 methods are placed on one class and it involves huge refactoring of code

Comment: Is there any process on this issue.

Comment: @Jiayao, there is no "one size fits all" solution as many of the methods have different signatures. I'm marking SetUp's as correct answer because it could still simplify the issue by having an interface with a set of funcs that match what's needed.f